# Regression, Independence & Normality of x and y variables (not residuals)

Tags: regression, independence, normality-assumption

I am trying to predict productivity of inbound process of a warehouse using

y-value = productivity in terms of pcs/hr

x-value = # pcs and ratio pcs/SKU. (where SKU = stock keeping unit)

Basic hypothesis -->

(1) the more work there are (busier people are), the more they rush and the better the productivity.

(2) In addition, since people handle 1 SKU only once, the more pcs/SKU, means the less time you have to spend per piece (ie if it takes 1 min to input information for 1 SKU, you could do 1 pcs in one minute at 1pcs/SKU or 100 pcs in one minute at 100pcs/SKU).

Questions -->

(1) does y variables and both of the x variables have to be normally distributed? I understands the residuals need to be normally distribution, but does the input and output itself also have to be normally distributed?

(2) The number of pcs is contained in both x1 and x2, does this pose a problem. I believe this will create dependency problem?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Does *y* include all inbound `pcs` (divided by total number of hours of operation I'm guessing?) or just those that are handled by the end of the day?

Answer (score 1):

For question (1), it is as you said. The residuals do need to be normally distributed, but the X and Y need not be.

For question (2), it is alright to use the fraction. The dependency problem arises when there is a linear relationship between #PC and #PC/SKU, but here there should not be one. SKU is not constant (if it is this variable is not informative), so a simple linear relationship between the two variables you want to include in your regression probably will not exist unless SKU itself is correlated with #pc.

Comment: Normality of the residuals can support inferences about confidence intervals, but it is contentious to suggest that it is essential for using regression to make predictions. There are some relevant answers on http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/does-the-non-normality-matter-in-using-regression-for-prediction?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

How much of a correlation do there need to be for it to become a problem? cov(piece,piece/sku) > absolute value(0.5) ?

From my understanding the number of SKU $\le$ number of pieces. 
So if the number of pieces increases the number of SKU will certainly increase. Although it is not true that you will have higher pcs/SKU simply because the number of pieces is large.